# WebLogic Pool Driver Doesn't Support XA driver

Tags: java, spring, weblogic, jta

I am working in a typical Dev->QA->Production environment, and it appears that our Dev environment is configured differently than our QA environment, but I'm not sure where to look for the problem, as I'm not very familiar with WebLogic's core configuration.

I've developed a web service that uses the Spring framework's distributed transaction support, and all of our JNDI connection entries on the Weblogic server are configured to use the Oracle XA driver. While everything works just fine in our development environment, I am getting the following error on QA:

```
 org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: 
      Could not get JDBC Connection;
 nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Pool connect failed : 
      java.lang.Exception: WebLogic Pool Driver doesn't support XA driver, 
      Please change your config to use a Non-XA driver
```

From what I can gather, this is a configuration issue with Weblogic itself, not the individual JNDI data sources.

I know it's not a lot to go on, but if someone could give me some idea where to start looking, I would appreciate the help.

Comment: For sure Type 4 drivers can be in XA. So can you provide an information on how you initialize the driver? Parts of XML?

Comment: I'm using the spring framework to initialize a JNDI connection.

     <jee:jndi-lookup id="myDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/data"/> 
  
     <bean id="appealsDao" class="com.mystuff.dao.AppealsDao" init-method="initDao">
       <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource"/>
     </bean>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out our WebLogic Admin had not restarted the connection pool as he said he did. Sorry for posting the question. Everything is working as expected now.